# Does smoking a single cigarette measurably harm your body?

Tags: cigarettes, nicotine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does smoking cigarettes cause lung cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/does-smoking-cigarettes-cause-lung-cancer)

Most of the data I've seen on smoking concentrates on the effects of smoking n cigarettes per day, or per week, over a long period of time. Is there any data on what damage is done to the body by smoking a single cigarette?

Comment: This is a good question; shame the accepted answer does not appear to address it in any way.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate?  One is about lung cancer, one is about any harm to the body.

Comment: Very weird duplicate, would vote to re-open if I could. *One* cigarette is unlikely to cause lung cancer, but does cause immediate measurable harm - its smoke contains chemicals for which there's no safe level of exposure, and has immediate effects like shutting down and harming alveoli and [increasing stiffness of the arteries](http://www.zmescience.com/research/just-a-single-cigarette-has-very-harmful-effects/).

Comment: One cigarette..Definitly not..see this risk calculator https://shouldiscreen.com/English/lung-cancer-risk-calculator